# Specific directive (AngularJS) or some template loading before all scripts get content

Tags: angularjs, javascript-framework, angularjs-directive

I have a script when the page loads:

> 200 OK
>           45ms
>   angular.min.js (line 100)
>   /customers/create.form.tpl
>       
>   200 OK
>           44ms    
>   angular.min.js (line 100)
>   /customers/new.json
>       
>   200 OK
>           41ms    
>   angular.min.js (line 100)
>   /customers/new.json
>       
>   200 OK
>           41ms

I want, before AngularJS loads all scripts, a page-loading template until all scripts are loaded and when the scripts are loaded, the user can use the product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many ways to go about this:

1) You can create a loading mask that covers everything in your application and has a ng-hide binded to a variable that is in the rootscope and gets set to true at .run(). This way when Angular loads and initializes you get the loading mask hidden. No need for a directive, no nothing.

2) You can have a directive that hides itself. This way, before angular gets initialized, the loading element shows up on the page. Then, after initialization, the directive applies some sort of CSS class on the loading element and fades it out and then removes it from the dom.

3) You can have a special loading div that remains active even after the framework has loaded (maybe you have an ajax request that needs to complete as well). In this case, 1) can work the same as before, just set the rootScope variable to true only after a finalized ajax request.